# He is "used to seeing" her kiss other men

Tags: used-to

I understand that we use 'used to' for things that happened regularly in the past.

But the following "used to" is different in someway, also the format of verb is *ing* form.

> MICHELLE Keegan is adamant her husband Mark Wright doesn’t mind watching her intimate love scenes because he **is used to seeing** her kiss other men. [The Sun](https://www.thesun.co.uk/tvandshowbiz/1724362/michelle-keegan-is-adamant-her-husband-mark-wright-doesnt-mind-watching-her-raunchy-love-scenes/)

Is it mean he saw here kissing other man one time? or regularly in the past?

Comment: check out the "is accustomed to" meaning.

Comment: I will assume this person is an actress who kisses men as a part of her work on film, TV or the stage. Her husband is not threatened by her kissing other people within the context of her work. He is used to it.

Comment: @TRomano Thank you. It is great I know that we can "used to" with regularly things in present. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accustomed+to

Comment: @Shannak - Just to expand on what TRomano is saying, make sure you understand the difference between *used to* and  **is** *used to*.  "I used to *X*" means "In the past I did *X*."  "I **am** used to *X*" means "I am accustomed to *X*."

Comment: @stangdon Thank you, I got it: one is "be + used to" the another one is just "used to" https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_used-be-used-to.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*BE + used to* is an idiomatic expression meaning *to be accustomed to something* . In this phrase, *to* functions as a preposition so it takes a gerund or noun phrase complement.

---

Just in case you wonder why *her* followed by an infinitive verb(kiss), the reason is that *to see* is a *verb of perception* that often takes a bare infinitival complement.

Answer (score 1):

Here `is used to seeing` means the person is aware of the act (her kissing other men) and has seen it on a regular basis (maybe multiple movies with such scenes!).